# How do I declare and assign a variable on a single line in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, variables

I want something like

```
DECLARE myVariable nvarchar[MAX] = "hello world".
```

Bonus points if you show me how to encode a quote in the string.

E.g.:

I want the string to read

```
John said to Emily "Hey there Emily"
```

my attempt would be

```
DECLARE myVariable nvarchar[MAX] = "John said to Emily \"Hey there Emily\""
```

Comment: The string delimiter in SQL Server is `'`, not `"`.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Here goes:

```
DECLARE @var nvarchar(max) = 'Man''s best friend';
```

You will note that the `'` is escaped by doubling it to `''`.

Since the string delimiter is `'` and not `"`, there is no need to escape `"`:

```
DECLARE @var nvarchar(max) = '"My Name is Luca" is a great song';
```

The second example in the MSDN page on [`DECLARE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) shows the correct syntax.

Comment: You can also initialize from a select statement, eg: declare @eid uniqueidentifier = (select top 1 id from t_Event)

Answer (score 18):

on sql 2008 this is valid

```
DECLARE @myVariable nvarchar(Max) = 'John said to Emily "Hey there Emily"'
select @myVariable
```

on sql server 2005, you need to do this

```
DECLARE @myVariable nvarchar(Max) 
select @myVariable = 'John said to Emily "Hey there Emily"'
select @myVariable
```

Answer (score 6):

You've nearly got it:

```
DECLARE @myVariable nvarchar(max) = 'hello world';
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) for the docs

For the quotes, SQL Server uses apostrophes, not quotes:

```
DECLARE @myVariable nvarchar(max) = 'John said to Emily "Hey there Emily"';
```

Use double apostrophes if you need them in a string:

```
DECLARE @myVariable nvarchar(max) = 'John said to Emily ''Hey there Emily''';
```